# How to get the keyboard to display on top of all views in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm relatively new to react-native and I was wondering how to display the on screen keyboard with a z index of 5000 (can be anything as long as it's greater than other views).
At the moment the keyboard pushes several view up and appears at the bottom.

This causes a lot of the text to appear over my TextInput views.

Ideally I'd like the solution to be applicable for both Android and IOS.

Thanks in advance for any help and support.

Patrick

Comment: use keyboard avoiding view ? https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: I take this back - I was just using it incorrectly due to inexperience.
Thank you @ucup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've now fixed this I'll post my solution for others to benefit from.
@ucup was right suggesting `KeyboardAvoidingView` but due to the changes in react-native a few updates are required.

If your in the position where you are using `KeyboardAvoidingView` and its doing nothing, you may find this interesting:

- you need to add `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` to the main view inside your KeyboardAvoidingView
- You need to use the `Keyboard` library from react-native to listen for the keyboard opening. When opened you may want to have a different margin value on some of your views when closed.

Some of the credit for this answer has got to go to other Stack Overflow users. For me, this is just a number of answers combined to make a workable solution for me.